# How to update the EFI firmware of a replacement logic board of a MBP mid-2015 to make it compatible with Mojave?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, efi

Apple has put me in a pickle. I had a lot of parts (battery, display, logic board) of my MBP mid-2015 replaced at the local Apple Store. When it was returned to me, it had a big new problem: it would keep booting into internet recovery mode (although it eventually did boot), but eventually ended up freezing while I was using it. Trying to reboot into recovery mode put me in the same internet recovery cycle

However, it turns out that my MBP runs fine from a bootable external backup SSD over USB. Since running Disk First Aid at that point found no errors on the internal SSD, I thought I would try to reinstall Mojave from the SSD, but when I did so, the installer refused, informing me that my Mac had an incompatible firmware version and suggesting that I try to install Mojave on a HFS+ disk! (alas, my MBP's flash drive is formatted as APFS encrypted). It was then that I realized that what must have happened is that the replacement motherboard has an earlier firmware version that is incompatible with OS X 10.14.1 installed on the MBP's internal flash drive, and the so-called "geniuses" at the Apple Store didn't think about this.

The problem is this: how can I update the logic board firmware so that it is compatible with Mojave? I just tried an internet recovery install of Mojave, but the installer refused for the same reasons as before (incompatible firmware). I can't even see a way to downgrade the internal flash drive to HFS+ …

Is my MBP able to run from the external SSD because it happens over USB, or because that SSD happens not to be encrypted?

Comment: can you extract it from the installer package ?

Comment: I did some research on this forum and it appears that it's impossible just to upgrade the firmware in that way …

Comment: the firmware is a part of the Mojave Installer package

Comment: I do not think it is a firmware problem, Mojave can be installed on 5 Yr old Macs, it is more likely your SSD needs repair

Comment: See above. While booted from the external SSD, I ran Disk Utility, and it found no errors! Boot ROM is MBP114.0172.B25, SMC version 2.30f2.

Comment: still, when Mojave tries to update the Firmware it runs in to a problem. As I said the installer package contains `LegacyFirmware.bundle`

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting that I do?

Comment: assuming by now you have made a back up of your data, ? do a new fresh install (reformatting the disk)

Comment: Do you mean erase as APFS (formatted) and then run the installer? Not sure why there would be anything wrong with the flash drive since it wasn't replaced.

Comment: ok, your choice

Comment: Perhaps you need to first install High Sierra?

Comment: If Apple repair screwed up, you should take it back and make them do it properly. Why are you spending your own time to correct a problem they created?

Comment: What @Wowfunhappy said.  I find it odd that Apple wouldn't install the latest OS on a machine that had that many components replaced.  That said, all updates are available as a download and are automatically applied through regular system updates.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Because I had already made five 20-minute trips to the Apple Store in two weeks. Frankly, I'm somewhat doubtful that they would have figured this out.

Comment: @Allan Not sure what point you're making. My MacBook Pro obviously represented a situation they hadn't planned for: the hardware had stock firmware from years ago (because of the replacements), yet my MBP had the latest OS installed which supposed (and required) the latest firmware.

Comment: What I'm saying is that assuming what you are saying is true, the Apple store *failed* at what they were doing.  If you bought and paid for a service, you should either a) get them to fulfill that service or b) get a refund.  This is like saying you paid the dealer to change your engine and transmission but it doesn't work so you're going to attempt to reprogram the car's computer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me outline the solution here in case any one else encounters the same problem.

The installer wouldn’t allow me to select the internal flash drive of my MacBook Pro, and the precise installer error message was “This Mac needs a firmware update in order to install to this volume. Please select a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume instead.”

So there were 2 solutions:

1. Backup the internal flash drive, erase, reformat as HFS+, and run the installer again.
2. Install Mojave on an external HFS+-formatted drive.

Explanation: with the “stock” firmware of a replacement logic board, the installer expects an HFS+-formatted drive, and won’t update the firmware until it can install the OS on an HFS+-formatted drive.